# WordPress - Change the Contact Form 7 ajax loader gif

Tags: ajax, wordpress, contact-form-7

How do I change the contact form 7 ajax loader? I tried a few tutorial links but nothing seems to be working due to the recent update in the plugin :(

Comment: http://www.thriveuk.com/quick-tips-change-default-contact-form-7-ajax-spinner/

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('wpcf7_ajax_loader', 'my_wpcf7_ajax_loader');

function my_wpcf7_ajax_loader () {
    return  network_home_url() . '/assets/themes/ips-helpdesk/images/ajax-loader.gif';
}
```

[link](https://gist.github.com/schalkburger/9ec0103f698d12ca167f)